# Talend - cannot use globalMap.get() in tmap

Tags: java, talend

I have tried every possible combination  in my tmap, and I am frustrated beyond belief

i set my global variable in a tJava like so

```
globalMap.put("table_id",22);
```

then later down the component line I call the global map in the out schema of a tMap[image]

globalMap.get("table_id");

and get the following error

```
Error Line: 2539
Detail Message: Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to int
There may be some other errors caused by JVM compatibility. Make sure your JVM setup is similar to the studio.
```

thins I have tried

```
(Integer)globalMap.get("table_id")   
((Integer)globalMap.get("table_id"))   
Integer.parseint(globalMap.get("table_id"))
```

any combination will not work, but simply putting the number 22 will work

any help would be extremely helpful

Comment: Both `((int)globalMap.get("table_id") )` and `((Integer)globalMap.get("table_id") )` work for me. Perhaps try running Talend under a different JVM.  Here is an example of how to do so, just swap out the paths with your own.

`C:\Talend\Talend-Studio-20141207_1530-V5.6.1\Talend-Studio-win-x86_64.exe -vm "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\server\jvm.dll"`

Comment: or you can also try to store value as string and then convert...so in tjava use globalMap.put("table_id", "22") .. and in tmap use Integer.parseInt((String)globalMap.get("table_id"))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer lies in this statement:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to int

So, it is definitely a Casting issue. I know for sure that : `(Integer)globalMap.get("table_id")` should work!

If it doesn't work, the error message will certainly be different than "Type mismatch"!

- note 1: it would better to use the native component "tSetGlobalVar" to store a value in the globalMap.
- note 2: context variables should not be modified dynamically in Runtime, because they are not thread-safe (globalMap is!).

Answer (score 0):

You can use context variable instead.

Step 1. Declare the variable in Context.

Step 2. Assign the variable where you are assigning the value. e.g. context.table_id=22;

step 3. use this context variable in tMap component.

Answer (score 0):

i agree with @mhassine that 
(Integer)globalMap.get("table_id") should work, but i only got it to work with

```
(int)globalMap.get("table_id")
```

maybe this is a quirk with 6.3, but yea cant explain it